# SQL Server calculating the total time below a threshold value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Perhaps someone could help me.  I have been trying to create a query that summarizes the amount of time an item has been below a threshold value.   My data looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to find the latest date that the NR column was LESS THAN OR EQUAL to the **threshold value of 5**.  My data is best visualized in the chart below:
[image]

For the case of A, the last point is above 5 so this would not give a value.  B is equal to or below the threshold at 2/8/2017 and C is never above.  In this case, I would use the first series event (circled).

The code I created nearly gets me the answer.   Note that I have a final step in the code that calculates the data difference in weeks from the point that it dropped below the threshold to the last point below the threshold.  For example in B - it would be the difference in weeks between 2/8/2017 and 2/28/2017.

Code is:

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TAB', 'U') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #TAB; 

  CREATE TABLE #TAB (SL VARCHAR(5), NR FLOAT, Date Date)
INSERT INTO #TAB VALUES
('A',   '10',   '1/1/2017'),
('A',   '4',    '1/15/2017'),
('A',   '12',   '2/1/2017'),
('A',   '4',    '2/7/2017'),
('A',   '3',    '2/15/2017'),
('A',   '6',    '2/28/2017'),
('B',   '10',   '1/1/2017'),
('B',   '8' ,'1/15/2017'),
('B',   '7' ,'2/1/2017'),
('B',   '5',    '2/7/2017'),
('B',   '4',    '2/15/2017'),
('B',   '4' ,'2/28/2017'),
('C',   '4',    '1/1/2017'),
('C',   '4',    '1/15/2017'),
('C',   '3' ,'2/1/2017'),
('C',   '3',    '2/7/2017'),
('C',   '3' ,'2/15/2017'),
('C'    ,'2',   '2/28/2017')





;WITH CTE1 AS(

  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SL ORDER BY Date) Rn_ix  FROM [#TAB])
 ,
CTE2 AS 

(
SELECT 
CTE1.SL,
NR,
CTE1.Date Max_Date
FROM CTE1 INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(Date) Date, SL FROM CTE1 GROUP BY SL) NEW ON CTE1.Date = NEW.Date AND CTE1.SL = NEW.SL 
)
, 
CTE3 AS 
(
  SELECT 
  CTe1.SL,
  MIN(Date) Sample_date_Max,
  MAX(Rn_IX) as Max_Row_Number,
  CTE2.Max_Date
  FROM CTE1 INNER JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.SL = CTE2.SL 
  WHERE CTE1.NR <= 5
  GROUP BY CTE1.SL, CTE2.Max_Date
 )
 , 
 CTE4 AS
 (
 SELECT SL, MAX(Date) as SampleDate, MAX(Rn_ix) Rn_IX 
 FROM CTE1 WHERE NR >5  GROUP BY SL

 ),


  CTE5 AS
  (SELECT CTE1.SL, CTe1.Date, NR 
  FROM CTE4 
  INNER JOIN CTE1 ON CTE4.Rn_IX = CTE1.Rn_ix-1

  and CTE4.SL = CTe1.SL )

  SELECT 
  CTe2.SL,
  DATEDIFF(WEEK, CTE5.Date, CTE2.Max_Date) as Weeks_Under,
ISNULL(CTE5.NR, CTE2.NR) AS NumericResult

  FROM CTE5 FULL OUTER JOIN CTE2 ON CTE2.SL = CTE5.SL
  ORDER BY CTE2.SL
```

This gives me the following result:

[image]

B is correct - it has been below 5 for 3 weeks and the first result value after it crossed was 5.
A is correct - there is no current value below 5.  It dropped below but came back above.   The numeric result is the latest value 
C is incorrect - C was always below 5 and I would like to see the first value of the series (01/01/2017, 4  in this case) in the numeric result and 8 weeks in the weeks under category.

In short I want the most recent period below or equal to 5 and the corresponding numeric result.

The output should look like this:

[image]

I would really appreciate any help on this.  Apologies in advance if this question is poorly worded.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I'm understanding the query logic...

WeeksUnder is either the difference in weeks between the start date and the end date if it's never been above the threshold OR the difference in weeks between the last date above and the end date if it has been above the threshold.

NumericResult is either the latest NR if it's currently above the threshold or has never been above the threshold OR the first NR where it went below the threshold.

In that case, it's just a matter of building this logic into a query like this:

```
SELECT SL,
       WeeksUnder = MAX(CASE WHEN LastDateAbove IS NULL THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, FirstDate, LastDate) / 7 WHEN LastDateAbove != LastDate THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, LastDateAbove, LastDate) / 7 END),
       NumericResult = MAX(CASE WHEN [Date] = COALESCE(LastDateAbove, LastDate) THEN COALESCE(NextNR, NR) END)
FROM
(
    SELECT T.SL,
           T.NR,
           T.[Date],
           C.LastDateAbove,
           C.FirstDate,
           C.LastDate,
           NextNR = (SELECT TOP 1 NR FROM #TAB WHERE SL = T.SL AND [Date] > C.LastDateAbove ORDER BY [Date])
    FROM #TAB T
    CROSS APPLY
    (
        SELECT LastDateAbove = MAX(CASE WHEN NR > 5 THEN [Date] END),
               FirstDate = MIN([Date]),
               LastDate = MAX([Date])
        FROM #TAB
        WHERE SL = T.SL
    ) AS C
) AS T
GROUP BY SL;
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.  Never thought of using cross apply - and this still confuses me a bit.   Thanks for the help - this is amazing - works great